# Find out who committed a specific svn prop (svn:ignore) on a directory

Tags: svn, svnignore

In my svn project there is a directory which has an svn:ignore property. Now i want to find out which committer set this property on this directory and the corresponding revision.

How can i do that on commandline?

[I'm on Linux. GUI-options to find that out are also welcome.]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225787/how-to-detect-modified-properties-using-svn-log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the svn-commandline doen't provide the functionality, and I didn't find a good script for my use case, so i just wrote my own which does exactly what i wanted in my question. I posted it in the related post, to avoid duplication: [how to detect modified properties using SVN log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225787/how-to-detect-modified-properties-using-svn-log/4861868#4861868)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a mechanism easily listed in [The Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.manip), which seems surprising.

If it comes to it you could do a binary search over revisions using `svn propget svn:ignore directory -r<foo>`, starting at the half-way point and moving up or down if the property is there or not -- it'll take at most 20 tries if you've got fewer than a million commits...